# CNAME on XName.org / Newbie Question

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I have about 20 domains "pointing" to my server via A-type DNS records, now that I am moving servers I found it rather tedious to change the IP addresses for all of them and thought that adding a CName would make more sense.

I cannot, however, figure out how to add a CNAME-type record for the domain name itself, and not any subdomains (I am using xname.org as my DNS provider).

So what exactly to I put into the Alias field for the TLD itself?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - it's not allowed to put a CNAME in the apex of a domain (i.e in the same place as the NS and SOA records).

See §3.6.2 of [RFC 1034](http://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=1034)

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node,
>   no other data should be present; this
>   ensures that the data for a canonical
>   name and its aliases cannot be
>   different

Comment: Why not? it makes total sense to have

Comment: foo.com -> someotherhost.com
www.foo.com -> someotherhost.com

Comment: @clops: The quote from RFC 1034 already explains why. DNS would have to either a) merge the SOA and NS records of `foo.com` and `someotherhost.com` (breaks stuff), b) only display SOA/NS of `someotherhost.com` (breaks stuff), or c) only display SOA/NS of `foo.com` (breaks stuff).