# Networksolutions cname blank alias

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, internet, cname-record

Using NetworkSolutions Advanced DNS - I'm able to configure things like:

www.mysite.com

mail.mysite.com

Everything works great, until I go to http://mysite.com - since there is not DNS and it won't let me enter blank alias in CNAME - it obviously fails...

So, is there a way to point http://mysite.com to http://www.mysite.com?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CNAME on XName.org / Newbie Question](http://serverfault.com/questions/184940/cname-on-xname-org-newbie-question)

Comment: See "Using the root domain name (no www.) with google sites" http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Apps/thread?tid=7dd4cd04d7a2bf70&hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/184940/cname-on-xname-org-newbie-question).

No, you can't do that - you must do it the other way around:

```
www.mysite.com. IN CNAME mysite.com.
```

Better yet, just put the same IP address in as an `A` record for both the domain name and the `www` prefix.

Comment: Ok I may have not been clear enough. I have site developed in Gooogle Sites, e.g. http://sites.google.com/mysite; I'm pointing CNAME from NS like this: www.mysite.com to ghs.google.com; so http://www.mysite.com works well, but http://mysite.com doesn't

Comment: no, because you can't have a CNAME for a bare domain.  You need to point the bare domain at some _other_ service, which then HTTP Redirects to the Google site.

Comment: And what would example of such service be? Can NS do it? GoDaddy?

Comment: OK. Just paid NetworkSolutions $12 per year to enable Web Forwarding; problem solved